# How to find maximum value depends on two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

**what I have?**

I have a dataframe looks like that:

```
      id1   id2      max_value   
0      1     3       50748.0     
1      1     3       50631.0     
2      1     4       55876.0     
3      1     4       56424.0     
4      1     5       28242.0     
5      1     5       28316.0
```

**what I want to get?**

for each id1, id2 I want to get the max_value. for the example above:

```
      id1   id2      max_value   
0      1     3       50748.0     
1      1     4       56424.0     
2      1     5       28316.0
```

**what I have tried?**

I tried to use groupby inside groupby but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

I found the right answer: groupby with 2 columns

```
df = df.groupby(['id1', 'id2'])['max_value'].agg('max').reset_index()
```